# Making some part of each array string(elements) as bold by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to make the text Bold for CMS: and for remaining it should be norrmal in same(one) string.
How can i do that if complete string is coming in the form of array elements,,, There are multiple value(string) to print. all the avlues will be passed through an array and we have to print the result in the said format. pls, help me.

**CMS:** Centers for Medicare & Medicaid Services

**DOE:** Department of Education

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Dont make duplicates of your own question 15 minutes later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845356/make-bold-some-part-of-a-string-using-javascript

Comment: Looks like an exact dup of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845356/make-bold-some-part-of-a-string-using-javascript) by the same person.  Marking to close as a duplicate.  You should edit your previous post if you want to add more info.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've posted no proof of trying, I'll give you some pointers.

Use regex to detect the start of the line using `^` and finish at the colon.
Wrap it in `strong` tags before you print it
Voila